# Can't open below URL in UIWebview

Tags: ios

I can't open below URL in UIWebview

```
http://ad.doubleclick.net/click%3Bh%3Dv8/3ccb/3/0/%2a/v%3B260459540%3B0-0%//3B1%3B42477956%3B2825-320/56%3B38531391/38549148/1%3B%3B%7Esscs%3D%3fhttp://www.google.com/
```

I m trying to open in UIwebview but not loading this URL

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:advertisement_url];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: what is the error? can you elaborate?

Comment: I m trying to open in UIwebview but not loading this URL

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:advertisement_url];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Comment: Did you try opening it your computer's browser?

Comment: Ya its works in computer's browser

Answer (score 1):

When I put that address into Chrome it fails to load the page (just goes blank), and in Internet Explorer it actually produces an error - 
 Windows cannot find 'http://ad.doubleclick.net/click%3Bh%3Dv8/3ccb/3/0/%2a/v%3B260459540%3B0-0%//3B1%3B42477956%3B2825-320/56%3B38531391/38549148/1%3B%3B%7Esscs%3D%3fhttp://www.google.com/' Check the spelling and try again.

I have used the following code in the simulator and just get a white screen similar to Chrome's behavior:
    `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ad.doubleclick.net/click%3Bh%3Dv8/3ccb/3/0/%2a/v%3B260459540%3B0-0%//3B1%3B42477956%3B2825-320/56%3B38531391/38549148/1%3B%3B%7Esscs%3D%3fhttp://www.google.com/"]; 
 

        NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

        [myWebView loadRequest:requestObject];`

If I change the URLWithString to a known website it works fine. Maybe double check that the link is correct?

Comment: URL : http://ad.doubleclick.net/click%3Bh%3Dv8/3cd0/3/0/%2a/v%3B260459540%3B0-0%3B1%3B42477956%3B2825-320/56%3B38531391/38549148/1%3B%3B%7Esscs%3D%3fhttp://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/little-red-helicopter/id389086132?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't open this url in my browser(Mozilla,Chrome). I think this site is using some kind of authorization . Please clear cookies from your browser and check whether you are able to load this url.

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ad.doubleclick.net/click%3Bh%3Dv8/3ccb/3/0/%2a/v%3B260459540%3B0-0%//3B1%3B42477956%3B2825-320/56%3B38531391/38549148/1%3B%3B%7Esscs%3D%3fhttp://www.google.com/"]; 

NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObject];